# Removing my Facebook login and creating a Stack Exchange login

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, linked-accounts

I've been looking into removing my Facebook (my only login) from my Stack Exchange networks accounts. I believe I've got a vague understanding of the correct way to do this from poking around, but I haven't been able to confirm this via the questions/answers I've looked at.

If I understand correctly, I need to do the following:

1. Create a new Stack Exchange account
2. Link this as a login to my current account
3. Remove Facebook from my list of logins

Will this have any ill effect? Will my sign-up date be shown differently, rep be affected, display name change, etc?

Comment: Yes this is correct and won't have any "ill effect".

Comment: Lovely - it was a bit more complex than expected - I believe I found a bug which I'll report separately. Thanks for your help and for the useful dupe link!