# When removing a Facebook account with the same email address as a StackExchange account, both are removed

Tags: bug, login

Recently I had [a query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251763/199965) relating to removing my Facebook account from my logins. I added in a new StackExchange account (using the same email address as my Facebook account) and both were listed. I then removed my Facebook account and neither were listed.

Luckily I was still logged in and able to re-add my StackExchange login - no idea what happens if an account has no logins.

I'm presuming this was because of them being the same email address based on the above, however I suppose this could be a separate bug. I'll leave this up to you to decide from the logs!